# How to get deployed library from truffle migration script?

Tags: truffle-migration

I have smartcontract that linked to library. I see both address in `truffle migrate` results but I want to have their address inside migration script.
While I can get contract's address by `contract.deployed()` it doesn't works for library. Awaiting from `deployer.deploy(library)` also returns nothing.